# WinSock Non-Blocking I/O

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, pipe

I have a WSASocket which when connected calls CreateProcess and servers cmd.exe, I wanted to implement a pipe in-between the processes hStdInput and the Socket Handle to parse commands that get sent over the socket, everything seems to run smoothly except for when I run a command like "ping 127.0.0.1" and have to wait for output, nothing shows up until I send more data over the socket, it seems my ReadFile call is blocking hStdOut handler from sending anything. Is there any way to fix this? Please don't be offended by my code I'm writing this project as a learning exercise, any help would be appreciated.

```
int syncShell(SOCKET *ConnectSocket) {
    int iResult = 0;
    printf("Spawning process\n");
    char Process[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
    sinfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);

    // create pipe for external commands
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    HANDLE hReadPipe = NULL, hWritePipe = NULL;
    iResult = CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &saAttr, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    if (iResult == 0) {
        printf("Pipe Error");
    }

    sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE) *ConnectSocket;
    sinfo.hStdInput = hReadPipe;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, Process, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo)) {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // implement pipe logic
    char buf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    DWORD len = 0;
    WSABUF DataBuf;

    while (1) {
        // causing the block?
        iResult = ReadFile((HANDLE) *ConnectSocket, buf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &len, NULL);
        if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("File Error or non-blocking");
        }
        else {
            printf("%d: %.*s\n", len, len, buf);
            WriteFile(hWritePipe, buf, len, NULL, NULL);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE); // waits till proc finishes
    CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    printf("Process exited\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're only going to sleep between reads it is completely pointless to use non-blocking I/O. You are better off blocking.

Comment: I put that there as a placeholder, even if it wasn't there though it would still block hStdOut.

Comment: Incomprehensible. It's also a continuing mystery why you're writing the process's own output back to it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest 207, in the original post I mentioned that I was gonna parsed the commands through the pipe. For simplicity sake I left that out, this may have been confusing to some...

Comment: Confusing to everybody except you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, according to the [`ReadFile`] document:

> For asynchronous read operations, hFile can be any handle that is
>   opened with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag by the `CreateFile` function,
>   or a socket handle returned by the [`socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) or [`accept`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept)function.

[`socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) create a socket handle with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` by default.
You will get error code 87(`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) if you pass a Overlapped handle and set the last parameter of `ReadFile` as `NULL`.
Sample to use Overlapped:

```
OVERLAPPED oRead = { 0 };
oRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);  
iResult = ReadFile((HANDLE)ConnectSocket, buf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &len, &oRead);
if (!iResult && GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(oRead.hEvent, INFINITE);
}
buf[oRead.InternalHigh] = 0;  //set string terminator for printf
printf("%s\n", buf);
WriteFile(hWritePipe1, buf, oRead.InternalHigh, NULL, NULL);
```

And it's better to use [`recv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) directly:

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, buf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
buf[iResult] = 0;  //set string terminator for printf
printf("%s\n", buf);
WriteFile(hWritePipe1, buf, iResult, NULL, NULL);
```

In addition, the overlapped socket could be used for redirected IO to child processes
You could create 2 pipes to communicate with child process:

```
iResult = CreatePipe(&hReadPipe1, &hWritePipe1, &saAttr, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
if (iResult == 0) {
    printf("Pipe Error");
}
iResult = CreatePipe(&hReadPipe2, &hWritePipe2, &saAttr, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
if (iResult == 0) {
    printf("Pipe Error");
}
```

Read from child process(`cmd.exe`), and send to client.

Or,

Just use [`WSASocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketa) instead of [`socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket), and do NOT specify the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.(recommended)

Comment: I realized that my child process couldn't handle buffers bigger than the string and that's why it wasn't giving me output, I'm still giving you the check because your answer was really informative Thank you!